# tealium button click track

Tags: analytics, event-tracking, tealium

I have an application page , where clicking on button "find product" , goes to search products page with a list of products mapped search criteria selected on previous page.

page 1. search criteria, "find product" button
page 2. products list matching search criteria

I would like to track "find product" click event. As soon as find product button clicked, user will be navigated to page 2.

Not sure, if a page load is occurring on a button click, will I be able to capture and track button click event ?

I am thinking to use "utag.link" implementation for this.
May be I am wrong, any suggestions helpful.

-Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the utag.link event on the mousedown interaction to give you a few milliseconds head start on the tracking.